# i want to parse strings and give them to variables

Tags: c#

I want to seperate name, surname and exam results and give them to variables. Can you show me a tip for this?

Here is my code

```
string[] studentData = new string[100];
        int[] visa1 = new int[100];
        int[] visa2 = new int[100];
        int[] homework = new int[100];
        int[] finalexam = new int[100];

        int i = 0;
        while (!Read.EndOfStream)
        {
            studentData[i] = Read.ReadLine();
            i++;
        }
        Read.Close();
```

and data file

```
Liam Smith 20 30 40 50
Emma Johnson 20 30 40 50
Noah Williams 20 30 40 50
Olivia Brown 20 30 40 50
William King 20 30 40 50
```

Comment: Rather than parallel arrays with each storing a portion of some data, you should use a class so you can keep interrelated elements together.  Beyond that it is not clear what problem there is to solve

Comment: i will add class at the end of the project

Comment: Use a class and File.ReadAllLines() to read in the lines for parsing

Comment: @Fatih At the end?  You should do it now.  Making a class to represent the data in the file is the proper thing to do.  You have 5 columns.  That is a class with 5 properties.

Comment: you're right, i am trying now

Answer (score 1):

One thing that can be handy in these situations is to create a simple class to represent the data, and add a `public static ClassType Parse(string input)` method to the class, which returns an instance of the class based on a string read from the file.

For example:

```
public class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Visa1 { get; set; }
    public int Visa2 { get; set; }
    public int Homework { get; set; }
    public int FinalExam { get; set; }

    public static Student Parse(string input)
    {
        // Input string cannot be null,
        if (input == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));

        // Input string must have 6 parts
        var data = input.Split();
        if (data.Length < 6) 
            throw new ArgumentException("Input string must contain 6 items");

        // The last 4 parts must be integers
        int visa1, visa2, homework, finalExam;
        if (!int.TryParse(data[2], out visa1))
            throw new ArgumentException("Third item (visa1) must be an integer");
        if (!int.TryParse(data[3], out visa2))
            throw new ArgumentException("Fourth item (visa2) must be an integer");
        if (!int.TryParse(data[4], out homework))
            throw new ArgumentException("Fifth item (homework) must be an integer");
        if (!int.TryParse(data[5], out finalExam))
            throw new ArgumentException("Sixth item (final exam) must be an integer");

        // All validation passed, so create and return a new student
        return new Student
        {
            FirstName = data[0],
            LastName = data[1],
            Visa1 = visa1,
            Visa2 = visa2,
            Homework = homework,
            FinalExam = finalExam
        };
    }
}
```

Then populating a list of this class from file data becomes really trivial:

```
List<Student> students = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Select(Student.Parse).ToList();
```